# (MacOS) OpenOffice dies within 30 seconds of starting

Tags: macos, openoffice

Starting a few days ago, OpenOffice suddenly crashes within 30 seconds of starting, even if you do absolutely nothing.  Monterey, the Java JRE, and OpenOffice are all "the very latest."  This also has nothing to do with any preferences-file.

From a recently-unearthed "diagnostic report" I find the following, which suggests that the problem is in the "check for update" process:

```
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libplds4.dylib                         0x16859d0a5 PL_HashTableLookupConst + 16
1   libnssutil3.dylib                      0x168a273da SECOID_FindOID_Util + 25
2   libsmime3.dylib                        0x1688c95b0 CERT_DecodeCertPackage + 335
3   libnss3.dylib                          0x168ed7b40 0x168e14000 + 801600
4   libnss3.dylib                          0x168ed7de3 0x168e14000 + 802275
5   libnss3.dylib                          0x168ed3ed0 0x168e14000 + 786128
6   libnss3.dylib                          0x168ed4cca 0x168e14000 + 789706
7   libnss3.dylib                          0x168ea0ef0 0x168e14000 + 577264
8   libnss3.dylib                          0x168e9f631 0x168e14000 + 570929
9   libnss3.dylib                          0x168e9d9f4 0x168e14000 + 563700
10  libnss3.dylib                          0x168e24b8d CERT_PKIXVerifyCert + 1437
11  libxsec_xmlsec.dylib                   0x1689ba337 SecurityEnvironment_NssImpl::verifyCertificate(com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::security::XCertificate> const&, com::sun::star::uno::Sequence<com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::security::XCertificate> > const&) + 1735
12  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x1687bbece http_dav_ucp::SerfSession::verifySerfCertificateChain(int, serf_ssl_certificate_t const* const*, int) + 2398
13  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168aabf2a 0x168aa4000 + 32554
14  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168bcaed6 X509_verify_cert + 2262
15  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168adf6dc ssl_verify_cert_chain + 444
16  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168ab8f60 ssl3_get_server_certificate + 368
17  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168ab7d9f ssl3_connect + 2319
18  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168ac7f1c ssl23_connect + 3100
19  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168ac826f ssl23_read + 79
20  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168aac801 0x168aa4000 + 34817
21  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168aa66ef serf_databuf_peek + 79
22  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168aae885 serf__process_connection + 309
23  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168aa5e24 serf_event_trigger + 180
24  libserf-1.dylib                        0x168aa5f09 serf_context_run + 185
25  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x1687b4110 http_dav_ucp::SerfRequestProcessor::runProcessor() + 112
26  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x1687b4316 http_dav_ucp::SerfRequestProcessor::processGet(com::sun::star::uno::Reference<http_dav_ucp::SerfInputStream> const&, std::__1::vector<rtl::OUString, std::__1::allocator<rtl::OUString> > const&, http_dav_ucp::DAVResource&, int&) + 54
27  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x1687befd7 http_dav_ucp::SerfSession::GET(rtl::OUString const&, std::__1::vector<rtl::OUString, std::__1::allocator<rtl::OUString> > const&, http_dav_ucp::DAVResource&, http_dav_ucp::DAVRequestEnvironment const&) + 263
28  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x1687a288a http_dav_ucp::DAVResourceAccess::GET(std::__1::vector<rtl::OUString, std::__1::allocator<rtl::OUString> > const&, http_dav_ucp::DAVResource&, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::ucb::XCommandEnvironment> const&) + 458
29  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x168788933 http_dav_ucp::Content::open(com::sun::star::ucb::OpenCommandArgument2 const&, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::ucb::XCommandEnvironment> const&) + 1763
30  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x16877f6fa http_dav_ucp::Content::execute(com::sun::star::ucb::Command const&, int, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::ucb::XCommandEnvironment> const&) + 2714
31  libucpdav1.dylib                       0x16878e082 non-virtual thunk to http_dav_ucp::Content::execute(com::sun::star::ucb::Command const&, int, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::ucb::XCommandEnvironment> const&) + 18
32  updatefeed.uno.dylib                   0x1683ff667 0x1683fa000 + 22119
33  updatefeed.uno.dylib                   0x1683fea4e 0x1683fa000 + 19022
34  updatefeed.uno.dylib                   0x1683ff152 0x1683fa000 + 20818
35  updchk.uno.dylib                       0x11a5a8b24 checkForUpdates(UpdateInfo&, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::uno::XComponentContext> const&, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::task::XInteractionHandler> const&, com::sun::star::uno::Reference<com::sun::star::deployment::XUpdateInformationProvider> const&) + 1460
36  updchk.uno.dylib                       0x11a59de00 0x11a595000 + 36352
37  updchk.uno.dylib                       0x11a59db1f 0x11a595000 + 35615
38  libsofficeapp.dylib                    0x10f46d5cf threadFunc + 15
39  libuno_sal.dylib.3                     0x10f56e855 0x10f568000 + 26709
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c9064e1 _pthread_start + 125
41  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c901f6b thread_start + 15
```

Comment: Try : Uninstall it, clean up folders, reinstall the latest version.

Comment: How did you check that it "also has nothing to do with any preferences-file"? Did you rename your profile folder?